# what is the difference between project 2010 and project server 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

What is the difference between 
project 2010 and project server 2010 
specially integration with sharepoint 2010 ?

Answer (score 1):

With Project 2010 Standard you can:

1. manage local projects
2. manage shared projects stored on network shares
3. manage resources stored inside of a project or manage resources stored in a resource pool file
4. link local and shared projects
5. if ODBC (database) is used to store project plans - you can build reports from the projects' data

Project 2010 Pro is Project 2010 standard + ability to work with Project Server

With Project Server 2010 you can all you can do with Project 2010 Standard + :

1. manage resources, security, views, templates, custom fields with lookups from one place
2. assign workflows to project plans
3. you get one more interface to your project plans: Project Web application. It costs slightly cheaper than Project: about $150 for PWA and $1500 for Project Pro.
4. your people can report their timesheets and progress directly to projects
5. you are getting better reports: Project Server includes BI reporting
6. API to work with projects which is much better than COM provided by desktop MS Project
7. Export tasks to SharePoint and Outlook (Exchange Server)
8. People believe that Project Server is Enterprise solution and it gives them some super enterprise functions they were never had with just desktop MS Project.

Practically you can implement the most of the Project Server features using combination of other technologies, but sometimes it is better to get something already done than reinvent a wheel.